# Use Visio shape data for calculations

Tags: microsoft-visio

Is it possible in MS Visio to perform calculations with shape data?

For example, if I had a stencil of a sink with a flow rate stored in its shape data, could I set up a "pipe" connector that could determine what the flow rate of everything attached to it is?

Building on the first example, if I had two sinks with pipes connected to a common pipe, could I get Visio to tell me what the flow in each pipe was and combine the flows in the common pipe?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way to enumerate the glues on a shape via the shapesheet.  You'd have to incorporate automation into your solution, at least to some extent.

You could have VBA code (or other automation) that fires when the glues change for a shape, and then process the existing glue state for the shape and generate a new shapesheet formula to make your calculations.

Then any simple text/value inputs theoretically could be incorporated to the formula, which would then update whenever the input(s) change(s).

But you would have to write at least some automation code to do it.

Comment: ShapeSheet environment cant apply to inumerate the glues on a shape!
Only VBA or other programming language…

Comment: I wrote in my answer that there's no way I know of to enumerate the connections within the shapesheet, and that you have to use automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try write macro which do
1. Define all sinks shapes connected to pipe
2. Will add the values of shape data for all shapes which connected to pipe

What you mean as "pipe" connector ?

Comment: In my example there would be sinks and they would be connected via a visio connector.  That connector would represent a physical pipe.  Ultimately, if I can get the pipe to show data such as how much is flowing through it, I could also give it a diameter and find the velocity, etc.